# suffix tree implementation in python

Tags: python, suffix-tree

Just wondering if you are aware of any C based extension in python that can help me construct suffix trees/arrays in linear time ?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347078/python-library-for-generalized-suffix-trees

Answer (score 8):

You can checkout the following implementations.

http://www.daimi.au.dk/~mailund/suffix_tree.html

https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/

https://github.com/kvh/Python-Suffix-Tree

A guy improved (first one) and put it here.

http://researchonsearch.blogspot.com/2010/05/suffix-tree-implementation-with-unicode.html

All are C implementations.