# How to generate suffix trees using a python library?

Tags: python, suffix-tree

I need python library that can construct suffix trees and especially generalised suffix trees. Could you suggest me some libraries. Thanks.

Comment: Why not try to implement it yourself?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See the following libraries.

- [suffixtree](https://code.google.com/archive/p/suffixtree/)
- [Python-Suffix-Tree](https://github.com/kvh/Python-Suffix-Tree)
- [SuffixTree](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/)
- [SuffixTree](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~mailund/suffix_tree.html) (same name different project, supports generalized suffix trees)
- [pysuffix](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pysuffix/) (This is suffix arrays)

Comment: Which one is faster?

Comment: lots of 404s now.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/csuffixtree/   This one is really fast generalized suffix tree, with python wrapper