# Good open source suffix tree implementation in python or C++

Tags: c++, python, data-structures, tree, suffix-tree

I'm looking for suffix tree implementation having this friendly API that mimics python dictionary:

```
import SubstringDict
d = SubstringDict.SubstringDict()
d['foobar'] = 1  
d['barfoo'] = 2
d['forget'] = 3
d['arfbag'] = 4
d['a']
>>> [1, 2, 4]
d['arf']
>>> [2, 4]
d['oo']
>>> [1, 2]
d['food']
>>> []
```

I took this example from this website: [Suffix Trees in Python](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/)
You may ask: "Why don't you use the implementation from the website?"
Well, apparently it has some memory leaks in python bindings so I can't using it with my large (1.2 million strings, about 200 MB) data set.

I would be even happy with C++ implementation (I can write python bindings on my own) with the following API:

```
SuffixTree<int> sf = SuffixTrie<int>();
sf['foobar'] = 1;
sf['barfoo'] = 2;
sf['forget'] = 3;

assetTrue(sf.find('a')==std::vector<int>({1,2}))
```

Any hints?

Comment: Something looks wrong in your example code, `>>>` in the wrong place maybe?

Comment: @aquavitae: Each `>>>` line above is the result of the previous instruction. It's been added to precisely the wrong lines to represent a Python interactive session.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996137/suffix-tree-implementation-in-python) something?

Comment: @RickyA  - no, definitely not. I know this related answers, I went through all libraries listed there and there is nothing really good (stable, scaling, with well defined API) there.

Comment: @aquavitae - if you like to point that sort of things (complain about my convention everyone else understands), please go somewhere else.

Comment: Ok,ok sorry.... Dont kill me please.